# Do the IoT Edge Built-In Metrics work in the iotedgehubdev simulator?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to determine if the Built-In Metrics for Azure IoT Edge (described [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/doc/BuiltInMetrics.md)) can be accessed when running locally with the edgeHubDev simulator for v1.0.9.  I've created a deployment.template.json with a edgeHub configuration like so

```
"edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0.9",
              "createOptions": {
                "User": "ContainerAdministrator",
                "ExposedPorts": {
                  "9600/tcp": {}
                },
                "HostConfig": {
                  "PortBindings": {
                    "5671/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "5671"
                      }
                    ],
                    "8883/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "8883"
                      }
                    ],
                    "443/tcp": [
                      {
                        "HostPort": "443"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "env": {
              "ExperimentalFeatures__Enabled": {
                "value": "true"
              },
              "ExperimentalFeatures__EnableMetrics": {
                "value": "true"
              }
            }
          }
```

At present I get a

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>    ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

whether I try to access them at http://edgeHub:9600/metrics on the IoT Edge module network or http://localhost:9600/metrics from my pc

Anyone know if this is possible or better yet able to tell me what I might be doing wrong?

output of `docker ps`

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                             COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                          NAMES
4753b9bb2416        mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor:1.0   "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"$…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                                                                                       SimulatedTemperatureSensor
d264bde9bfb1        mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0                            "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"$…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5671->5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8883->8883/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9600->9600/tcp   edgeHubDev`

Comment: When the simulator is running your workload, what is the output of ‘docker ps’?

Comment: did my best to get it represented in the original question.  please let me know if you need clarification on a specific field

Comment: adding some more color to this ... ive been able produce/consume the edgeHub metrics via an ExposedPort configuration when running in the simulator.  no such luck with the edgeAgent metrics though

Comment: The simulator doesn't run the edgeAgent (it uses docker-compose), so edgeAgent metrics won't be available in that environment.